# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I had created this method to check number of this record in the table
but it gives me this error message when the value of count(*) is 0 
i use this library to connect oracle db

**using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;**

```
 private int checkPort(int portID)
        {
            int intCount = 0;
            try
            {
                OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand();
                oraCommand.Connection = new DBManager().getConnection();
                oraCommand.CommandText = "select count(*) as num from wireless_port_oid where port_id=:port_id";
                oraCommand.Parameters.Add(":port_id", portID);

                OracleDataReader Reader= oraCommand.ExecuteReader();


                return intCount;
                while (**Reader.Read()**)//it gives exception here
//The err Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
                {  
                    intCount =Convert.ToInt32(Reader[0]);
                    Reader.Close();
                    oraCommand.Connection.Close();
                    oraCommand = null;
                    if (intCount > 0)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                Reader.Close();
                Reader.Dispose();
                oraCommand.Connection.Close();
                oraCommand.Connection.Dispose();
                oraCommand.Dispose();
                return 0;

            }
            catch (OracleException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is that return intCount doing there before the while?

Comment: some hints:
use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.executescalar%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get a single value (no need to iterate/use read). And you should use the `using` statmenet so that your command etc. gets disposed automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're closing the reader on Count = 0 and then trying to read it again in the while loop.

```
while (Reader.Read())//it gives exception here
//The err Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
                {  
                    intCount =Convert.ToInt32(Reader[0]);
                    Reader.Close();
                    oraCommand.Connection.Close();
                    oraCommand = null;
                    if (intCount > 0)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    } 
                    // if intCOunt == 0 then what? loop again
                }
```

**But your code is not valid - I just noticed that you have a  return intCount; just before the line you says has an error.** I assume that that's just example typo.

I would refactor your code to take adavantage of C#'s using statement:

```
private int checkPort(int portID) {
    string sql = "select count(*) as num from wireless_port_oid where port_id=:port_id";
    int intCount = 0;
    try {
        using(OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand()) {
            using(oraCommand.Connection = new DBManager().getConnection()) {
                oraCommand.CommandText = sql;
                oraCommand.Parameters.Add(":port_id", portID);
                intCount = oraCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OracleException exception) {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            // may be you shouldn't return 0 here possibly throw;
    }

    return intCount;
}
```